# how to search using the sum of case when in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to do implement a search in the generated data of the sum count of a case when in cakephp with or or conditions in each data.

```
SELECT `Branches`.`name` AS `Branches__name` , `Branches`.`code` AS `Branches__code` , (
COUNT(
CASE WHEN `prodCarried`.`carried` =1
THEN 1
END )
) AS `carried` , (
COUNT(
CASE WHEN `prodCarried`.`carried` =0
THEN 1
END )
) AS `unCarried`
FROM `branches` `Branches`
INNER JOIN `products_carried_per_branches` `prodCarried` ON ( prodCarried.company_id = Branches.company_id
AND prodCarried.branch_code = Branches.code )
WHERE (
`Branches`.`company_id` =200017
AND `Branches`.`deleted` =0
AND `prodCarried`.`deleted` =0
)
GROUP BY `code`
HAVING COUNT(
CASE WHEN `prodCarried`.`carried` =1
THEN 1
END ) =39
```

the picture shows the mysql result without the having code [image]

while this is my cakephp code, I want to implement the having sql into cakephp or condition to search the generated sum count or search the data name and code. is this possible or nah

```
$carriedCase = $query->newExpr()
        ->addCase(
            $query->newExpr()->add(['prodCarried.carried' => '1']),
            1,
            'integer'
        );
    $unCarriedCase = $query->newExpr()
        ->addCase(
            $query->newExpr()->add(['prodCarried.carried' => '0']),
            1,
            'integer'
        );
    //disctinct code
    $query ->select([
            'name',
            'code',
            'carried' => $query->func()->count($carriedCase),
            'unCarried' => $query->func()->count($unCarriedCase),
            'prodCarried.id',
            'prodCarried.validity_start',
            'prodCarried.validity_end',
    ]);
    $query ->distinct([
        'code'
    ]);
     $query->join([
      'prodCarried' => [
        'table' =>'products_carried_per_branches',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => [
          'prodCarried.company_id = Branches.company_id',
          'prodCarried.branch_code = Branches.code',
        ]
      ]
    ]);

    $query->where(function (QueryExpression $exp, Query $q) use($option,$search){
        $exp->eq('Branches.company_id', $option['company_id']);
        $exp->eq('Branches.deleted', 0);
        $exp->eq('prodCarried.deleted', 0);
        if(!empty($search)){
            $orConditions = $exp->or_(function (QueryExpression $or) use ($search) {
                $or->like('name', "%$search%");
                $or->like('code', "%$search%");
                //****************************

                return $or;
            });
            $exp->add($orConditions);
        }
    return $exp;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS you can refer to the aggregate of the select list:

```php
$query->having([
    'carried' => $searchCount,
]);
```

Otherwise you have to recreate the aggregate:

```php
$query->having(
    function (
        \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
        \Cake\ORM\Query $query
    ) use (
        $carriedCase,
        $searchCount
    ) {
        return $exp->eq(
            $query->func()->count($carriedCase),
            $searchCount
        );
    }
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Aggregates - Group and Having](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#aggregates-group-and-having)**